# Phonegap Open form submit to external Domain on web browser

Tags: javascript, forms, jquery-mobile, cordova, submit

I'm having a problem with phonegap to open a form submit on the web browser on Android and iPhone. I want to submit a form with js like this:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <form target="_blank" action="https://externalDomain.com">
      <input value="123" />
      <input value="456" />
    </form>
    <script>
      form.submit();
      // do something else
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

So the execution of this script happens in a file stored on the device lets say "index.html", and I want the submit to open on the browser, because I need the user to fill a payment processor form on "externalDomian.com". The user will then enter the app again and he could check if the payment was correctly processed.

Im using phonegap 2.0.0 on android I tried this config on config.xml, but it didn't help

```
<access origin="https://externalDomain.com" browserOnly="true" />
```

On iPhone I have the flag OpenAllWhitelistURLsInWebView set to NO on Cordava.plist, also din´t helped.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Do an AJAX submission of the form, that way the user isn't actually redirected to an external website but kept in your app:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <form id="foo-form" target="_blank" action="https://externalDomain.com">
      <input value="123" />
      <input value="456" />
    </form>
    <script>
    $('#foo-form').on('submit', function () {

        //create AJAX request to submit form
        $.get(this.action, $(this).serialize(), function (response) {
            //the `response` variable now holds what the server returned after the form submission
        });

        //stop regular submission of form
        return false;
    });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

You can then add the response to the DOM, allowing the user to fill-out the external form. And then bind to that form and do another AJAX submission.

Comment: I don´t think I can do that, because is a form from a payment processing site. I don´t know if it is even legal. I don´t mind the user to get out of the app, I totally prefer that so I also give the user the security he is giving he card info to the real payment site.

Comment: The only other way I can think to get the user back into your app is to create an `intent` for your app's domain and then somehow get your payment gateway to forward the user to a link that gets read by the `intent` or have them put a link on the confirmation page.

Comment: Sorry if I was not so clear, I´m going to edit the post now. I don´t the user to stay in the app, I want to open the submit on the user web browser, just for security reasons is the best way to proceed in fact the only way I have to proceed.

Comment: did you have any luck with this? I'm looking for a similar solution.